# Support for NSS in developer-mode ChromeOS?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, google-chrome-os, nss

first question.

I recently put kubuntu onto my chromebook via crouton, which was painless and awesome. However, it did necessitate putting it into developer mode. For some reason, this has removed ChromeOS's ability to authenticate SSLs for a couple of sites I use for work (but not all of them). I prodded the sysadmin, and he says the problem is the NSS library. Specifically:

> It is a problem with the NSS library version on the users OS. You can
>   by pass the problem by starting Chrome with; 
>   $ google-chrome-stable --ssl-version-max=tls1.1

I tried running that command (with and without the $) in Crosh, shell, and even bios command prompt. Nope (command not found, or some variation there of). [This page](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/platform) seems to suggest that NSS isn't favoured, but the sysadmin is unable or unwilling to change the protocol to OpenSSL. So I'm left with trying to install NSS support onto my post-crouton, dev-mode chromebook. Problem is, I have no idea how to do that. Worst case scenario, I can move my work environment totally from ChromeOS into the newly installed Kubuntu instance, but I'd rather not because ChromeOS is just such a pleasure to work on, for browser based work.

Does anyone know how to get NSS protocol SSLs working on dev-mode ChromeOS?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot re-run chrome from within chrome, so that command won't help.

NSS/OpenSSL aren't protocols, they're libraries that implement protocols.  Chrome OS uses NSS for some certificate management, but it uses OpenSSL (actually BoringSSL) for all network communication.

putting Chrome OS into dev mode though should not change its behavior at all when it comes to network protocol negotiation.  without more details, it's hard to guess at the issue.